# Delete vector of vectors that contain structs

Tags: c++, dictionary, hash, hashmap, destructor

c++ noob here.
I'm creating a limited hash map and I'm storing structs in vectors, inside a vector.
i.e:

```
struct bucket{
    V value;
    std::time_t time;
};

std::vector<std::vector<bucket>> limmap;

template <typename K, typename V>
ece2400::limited_hash_map<K,V>::limited_hash_map::limited_hash_map(std::size_t num_buckets , std::size_t bucket_size){
    for(int i = 0; i < num_buckets; i++){
        std::vector<bucket> temp(bucket_size);
        limmap.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

1. would it be better to use arrays instead of vectors?
2. How would I go about creating the destructor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I have no idea whether the function header is correct, but let's assume it is and it doesn't really matter, considering your question.

**1. Would it be better to use arrays instead of vectors?**

If you mean C-style arrays then I would advise not to use them. It's C++, use the standard library. Of course, C-style arrays are faster but more error-prone. If, on the other hand, you meant `std::array`, then the answer is no (sort of). To create `std::array` object, the parameter describing the amount of elements the array will hold has to be known compile-time (`constexpr`). This will probably not work in your function, because you could call it like this:

```
int bucket_size;
std::cin >> bucket_size; // value not known at compile-time

limited_hash_map(num_buckets, bucket_size);
```

Just stick to `std::vector` and you'll be fine :)

**2. How would I go about creating the destructor?**

You don't need to. `bucket` doesn't allocate any resources in constructor so you don't need to free anything. Eventually vectors will get destroyed, and when they do they will destroy all objects they hold, in your case `bucket` objects. Since they don't need any explicit destructors they will be destroyed automatically, without any issues.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Almost certainly no. Because the array would have to be dynamically sized you will have picked up many extra memory management responsibilities to look after the care and feeding of that dynamic allocation. Not the least of which having to comply with the [The Rule of Three or Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).
2. `vector` looks after itself pretty well. So long as `V` complies with the Rule of Zero, Three or Five you need do absolutely nothing in the destructor. This likely allows `ece2400::limited_hash_map` to take advantage of the Rule of Zero.